# java.lang.NumberFormatException : Not a valid char constructor input: aa

Tags: java, xml, tivoli

I have a xml job where I define resources:

```
 <Resources>
                    <Resource name="VMDSCP1"/>
                    <Resource name="VMDSCP2"/>
                    <Resource name="VMDSCP3"/>
                    ...............
                    <Resource name="VMDSCP26"/>
                    <Resource name="VMDSCP27"/>
 </Resources>
```

And create conversion for them:

```
<FromResources>
                          <FromResource name="VMDSCP1" symbol="a"/>
                          <FromResource name="VMDSCP2" symbol="b"/>
                          <FromResource name="VMDSCP3" symbol="c"/>
                          ..............
                          <FromResource name="VMDSCP26" symbol="z"/>
                          <FromResource name="VMDSCP27" symbol="aa"/>
</FromResources>
```

And everything running smooth until:

```
<Parameters>
                    <Parameter formula="(a+b+c+d+e+f+g+h+i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w+x+y+z+aa)/1024/1024"/>
</Parameters>
```

After which, following error ocures:

```
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: Not a valid char constructor input: aa
    at java.math.BigDecimal.bad(BigDecimal.java:1854)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.charParser(BigDecimal.java:1185)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:917)
    at java.math.BigDecimal.<init>(BigDecimal.java:896)
```

Could you please suggest how can I converse resources - what symbol can I use? Currently I use whole alphabet (a-z) but need 9 symbols more.

Best regards

Comment: Assuming [IBM Tivoli](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNHG7_7.3.0/com.ibm.ituam.doc_7.3/pdf/tuam_pdf_admin_processing.pdf), it says *symbol=”a-z”: This allows you to pick a variable which will be given the value
of the named resource. This can then be used by the formula parameter as part
of an arithmetic expression. This attribute is restricted to one lowercase letter
(a-z).*, so there's nothing you can do, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, IBM Tivoli.... I see, so I will have to find a workaround. Thank you a lot for support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a char can only contain a single character. `aa` is two. If you are missing 9 additional symbols, might I suggest using '1' through '9'  instead perhaps? Or maybe 'A' through 'I', or literally any other unicode character.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but I've already tried this - resources are numbers so I can't use numbers in conversion. and capital letters also throws error same like with "aa"